# How do I Change Navigation Background Color With CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, navigation

This is the site in question: http://bnurowing.com

I would like to change every part of the current orange navigation background with red (#bf2323).

Can someone please tell me the lines of CSS code I need to replace the values of?

I've tried changing some of the values but when I hover over 'Committee & Coaches' (About > Our Club), it turns to this red color when I want it to stay black.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: My apologies Diodeus, in future I will do my best to make my questions more generic so that they benefit others too :)

Answer (score 2):

Change `#F24830` in `style.css` to:

(line 291)

```
.sf-menu > li > a:hover, 
.sf-menu > li.sfHover > a, 
.sf-menu > li.current-menu-item > a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #BF2323;
}
```

(line 310)

```
.sf-menu li li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #BF2323;
}
```

Most modern browsers have an [inbuilt DOM inspection tool](http://bigemployee.com/4-simple-techniques-to-quickly-debug-and-fix-your-css-code-in-almost-any-browser/), so you can see where and what styles are being applied on the specific element(s).

Comment: Thank you so much YaMo, your solution worked perfectly! I've been spending an hour having a headache over this.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
li.current-menu-item > a {
background: ##bf2323;
}
```

Try That.